# Wicket textarea with default input

Tags: validation, input, textarea, wicket, default

I have a textarea which sometimes will have default text in it and sometimes not depending on values in the database. Right now, I'm using a model in the textareas constructor whose getObject() returns a string and it works fine for displaying the text it gets from the database:

```
myTextArea = new TextArea<String>("text", textModel);
```

Here's the problem though: I want to be able to call myTextArea.validate() before a user inputs anything in the textarea, and right now I always get a required error. Apparently, checkRequired() uses getInput() when validating the textarea, and the default value of getInput() is null.

Is there some way I can match the textarea's input with it's modelObject, or make the default input be determined by the text displayed in the textarea?

Comment: What's the reason you want to call validate() manually instead as part of the form validation process?

Comment: We automatically save even invalid data so that the user can return to an unfinished document and it still remembers his/her changes even if they where incomplete.
When a user returns to the document I need to check all fields and see if they are valid. If they are invalid they are stored in a list so that we can give the user feedback when he/she tries to send the invalid document.
Since each field saves it's own data automatically they are currently not in a shared form.

Answer (score 0):

getInput reads its value from the request parameter corresponding to your form component. I think you should override this method in your text area and make it return the value of the model if the original getInput returns null. For example:

```
public String getInput(){
  String originalInput = super.getInput();
  if(originalInput == null && textModel.getObject() != null)
   return textModel.getObject().toString();

  return originalInput;
}
```